# HTML5 custom elements and attributes

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am working with NopCommerce 4.2

When I open Views/Customer/Register.cshtml, I run into code:

```
<label asp-for="LastName" asp-postfix=":"></label>
<input asp-for="LastName" />
<nop-required />
<span asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
```

obviously **nop-required** is a custom element. But when I hover the mouse on it, it shows **"Nop.Web.framework.TagHelpers.Shared.NopRequiredTagHelper"** It seems some backend code is working with it. What is the name of this kind of syntax? Where can I find documentation about it?

similarly, the attribute "**asp-validation**" is also custom attribute. The backend side is **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression**

How do they work? I assume it will generate some JS code on front end?

Answer (score 0):

After days of research, it comes from TagHelper feature of ASP.NET Core

Full documentation can be found below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-3.1